# How to align the div in same row in angular 5 using bootstrap classes

Tags: css, angular, html, angular5

// here is input field with the label, "WLC Name" I want to align in the same row.

```
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label text-right">WLC Name</label>
           <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-11">
          <input type="text"value="BSNL-WLCXXX" class="form-control" formControlName="wlc_name"                                            id="wlc_name" #wlcname>

// I want to put below div in the same row, but it is not coming.
    <div>    
      <app-right-tooltip [toolTipText]="getToolTipText('system_basic_wlc_name')"></app-right-tooltip>
     </div>
    </div>
```

// html code for the tag  : app-right-tooltip

```
  <div>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign blue" style="font-size: 15px " aria-hidden="true" [popover]="getData()"
              popoverPlacement="right"
              [popoverOnHover]="false"
              [popoverCloseOnMouseOutside]="false">
        </span>
  </div>
```

[snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lccI9.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to float `app-right-tooltip`

```
<app-right-tooltip style="float:right"></app-right-tooltip>
```

Otherwise, you need to have some structure to wrap this component

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="md-2">...</div>
    <div class="md-10"><app-right-tooltip /></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
css

```
.exampleClass {
   dispaly: inline-block;
}
```

Html

```
<div class="exampleClass">    
  <app-right-tooltip [toolTipText]="getToolTipText('system_basic_wlc_name')"></app-right-tooltip>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, for the response bro, it was helpful though!